# What are the clock codes?

Tags: raspbian, gui

In Raspbian in the upper right hand corner there is a clock and when you right click it and select clock settings there is a field for clock format codes and changing this field will display the clock in different formats.
What are these formats or how can i find out what they are?(other than on stack exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is a little long to paste in full. You can get a full listing using `man date` in a terminal window, or take a look through [this list posted at man7.org](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) or [at die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date).

Answer (score 0):

Enter *man 3 strftime* in the terminal and you can read the Linux man page for date and time and set the digital clock as you wish.
(Right click on the digital clock, go to clock settings. Format codes: *man 3 strftime* is given there.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).